# How do you import jQuery plugins with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, jquery-plugins

I'm using Webpack v4, and I have jQuery plugins which I currently load into our app with the `webpack-merge-and-include-globally` webpack plugin (and then manually load these into the html file with a `<script>` tag) but I would like to be able to move this into our main app code, so that webpack can be aware of them. There's been issues where some dependancies/classes are loaded twice, once in the merge-plugin mentioned above, and again in the Webpack dynamic imports.

So far its been hit and miss trying to get jQuery plugins to load and properly attached to the jQuery object.

Is there a recommended way to import jQuery plugins, as its not like a normal JavaScript ES6 class which you can just prefix with `export class ClassName` or `export default class ClassName`, because the plugin is wrapped in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

Answer (score 0):

A few potential solutions:

## Option 1 - jQuery plugin that does not need its own global

```
import 'myapp/jquery-plugins/MyjQueryPlugin';
```

This one seemed potentially too good to be true / too easy, as it did not require new loaders.

Add the import statement without a name, just the script path. This should self execute the script, similar to how it would on a  load from HTML.

Note that this would not work with a script that needs to be Global. For that, use the expose-loader in option 2 to specify what globals to expose.

As I found that each plugin/library/class I had to work with required a different way of handling it, I will also mention some other methods I found useful, and may be useful to others:

## Option 2 - globals, such as jQuery

```
import 'expose-loader?exposes[]=$&exposes[]=jQuery!jquery';
```

This would import and execute it as it went, so that the next import line could use the global variable straight away.

## Option 3 - alternative for globals

```
import MyClass from './views/MyClass';
window.MyClass = MyClass;
```

You can import, and then set on the window yourself, but if you have several import statements, and the latter depend on the first one already being available, then this wont work, as its not yet defined. See option 2. This is my least favorite, but worth mentioning as a fallback.

## Option 4

Use the `[webpack-merge-and-include-globally][1]` plugin, but this is the one I was trying to avoid/reduce the use of, as its outside of "webpack's awareness."

## Others

There's also other loaders like [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader), which you can use as normal with a `!!` in the import, or with a .then promise to control execution after load.

```
import('raw-loader!someScript.js').then(rawModule => eval.call(null, rawModule.default))
```

This is the [example given by the docs in script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader) as an alternative, as script-loader is deprecated.